# Overlapping labels from two layers. Looking for rule that labels from one layer overrule labels from the other

Tags: qgis, labeling, rule-based

I am not a developer and I am asking for help to create a rule on label hierarchy across two layers. Specifically, I have a layer with rivers and a layer with towns. In case of an overlap of labels from the two layers, I want the town label to remain visible while the river label becomes invisible.

Comment: At first you could simply try to set the Z order and priority setting of the town layer label higher than those of the river layer. https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/label_settings.html#priority ; https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/label_settings.html#label-options

Comment: Thank you so much. That was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

At first you could simply try to set the [Label z-index](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/label_settings.html#label-options)  and [priority setting](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/style_library/label_settings.html#priority) of the town layer label higher than those of the river layer.

This will prioritize the display of label from town layer and/or display them on top.